# How do I take a pointer in a va_list from outside the function?

Tags: c++

I want to implement my own fscanf function in my application. But I couldn't manage to take my char pointer in my va_list. The code I'm trying to use is this:

```
scan(const char * _Format, ... )
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, _Format);
    int result = ::fscanf(_ptr, _Format, args);
    //va_end(args);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You can't pass a `va_list` to a function expecting `...`, the function must take a `va_list` parameter.

Comment: variadic template (from C++11) may help also: `template <typename ... Ts> int scan(const char* format, const Ts&... args) { return ::fscanf(_ptr, format, args...);}`